# How do I cite both name and year in parentheses in sn-jnl?

Tags: citing, natbib, brackets

I want to cite the name and year of publication in parentheses in `sn-jnl`. However, the various options that I have tried return an index number in brackets only:

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
    This is the result with the first citation \cite{WHO16}.
    This is the result with the second citation \citep{WHO16}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get the name and year of publication in parentheses?

Comment: Maybe something like this could work `\newcommand{\mciteyp}[1]{(\cite{#1}~\citeyear{#1})}`.... Then use `\mciteyp{WHO16}`

Comment: Thanks for your response. This does not work and returns: `([2] (year?))`

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "name" -- the title of the publication, the names of the author(s) of the publication, or maybe something else?

Answer (score 0):

I get the desired result by using:

`\documentclass[sn-basic]{sn-jnl}`

instead of:

`\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}`